# Data from one datagridview to another c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two datagridviews in one form which are having some similar colums
When the user clicks a button, the selectedrow's data of 2nd and the 3rd column of 2nd datagridview should go to the 1st and the 2nd column of the 1st datagridview. 
I've retrieved the data using

```
string strppno = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
string strpartno = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
```

and i can paste in the second datagridview using

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = strppno;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = strpartno;
```

how ever i cannot figure out how to loop it so that it can be used multiple times or or multiple selected values.

Can someone please help me out. I thank you in advance for any suggestions. 
[image: Image for reference]

first attempt.

```
for (int index = 0; index < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; index++)
{
int editIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
dataGridView1.Rows[editIndex].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[1].Value;
dataGridView1.Rows[editIndex].Cells[1].Value = dataGridView2.Rows[index].Cells[2].Value;
}
```

this bring out all the contents from the datagridview 2. I just want the selected one.

Second attempt.

```
string strppno = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
string strpartno = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();

for (int i = dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count; i < dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count + 1; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[i].Value = strppno;
    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[i + 1].Value = strpartno;
}
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count);
}
```

this kinda bring things that i want but in the wrong cell plus the loop keeps on running. :(
I kept fiddling around with the 2nd loop but can't get the expected results.. :(

Comment: looks like a nested for loop to me. have a look into iterating a 2D array - should help you :)

Comment: I tried it, but i doesn't seem to give the needed results. Could please show me an example.

Comment: could you please show me your attempt, and we'll see if we can point you in the right direction

Comment: Updated my ans. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So i got it... 
the problem happens when you add a new row to the dataGridView. It does not add after the existing data but adds before it. hence there is occurs an exception. 
Solution is below just in case anyone else needs it. :)

```
int count =0; // declare in public class

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
         dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count); // add rows before entering data inside the new dataGridView.
        }
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
        {

            {
                string value1 = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                string value2 = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = value1;
                dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value = value2;
            }
        }

        count =count + 1;
        dataGridView2.ClearSelection(); // I used this because i have to work with 4 dataGridViews 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this will be useful to you:

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.SelectedRows) {
                string value1 = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                string value2 = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                //...
                //also set the second datagrid from here too
            }
        }
```

So, in your example, you'll want to be using just the 2nd and 3rd Cell Value, and assigning them to your other datagrid :)

---

As a side note, to make your variables more readable/etc, you should get used to using camelCase,

i.e.

your `string strpartno` should become `string strPartNo`

as well as naming dataGridViews properly/etc

---

from your comment, I have realised your ***insertInto*** code needs to be amended slightly:

Currently, your placing them:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = strppno;
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value = strpartno;
                   ^
                   |
              this will only place it into index 0 of the datagrid
```

So, what i suggest is to first

```
  int count = ... //count number of rows in SecondDatagrid
```

Then do:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[count++].Cells[1].Value = strppno;
dataGridView1.Rows[count++].Cells[2].Value = strpartno;
                   ^
                   |
              this will only place it into next 
              available row of the datagrid
```

that way, you're still inserting into the first two columns, but not overwriting the values currently stored.

Comment: I actually need it on a button press event.. I'll try this right now... I use camelCase all the time. Editing so much frustrated me ... so eventually conventions started to change. :P :P :P 
I'll try this and let you know. :)

Comment: its giving me the same result which i was got in the first attempt. Once I select and add, it is goes in the dataGridView. But what happens case I need to add more rows ?? How do I achieve that

Comment: Say, there are a total of 10 rows in the dataGridView2 ... i want to add 1,3,4,7 to dataGridView1.  I select 1.. click add.. this works. Now when i select row no 3 and i click add, new row should be added in the dataGridView1 below the row 1 and similarly others should be added. Currently it replaces row 1.

Comment: Doesnt work :( :( Count keeps increasing data wont be added in the proper row. :(

Comment: *wont be added in the proper row* - could you explain?

Comment: Its actually getting added directly in the third row.. and then it show an exception.. if you want to try we can connect via team viewer, You can try or show me how is it to be done..

Comment: are you counting the right datagrid? *the one you're posting to?*

Comment: I guess i am .. and Now i've done so many changes, i am totally confused :P :P :P ^.^"